# NuSOAP: how to change content-type of request?

Tags: php, web-services, content-type, nusoap

When consuming a .NET WCF webservice I get the following response (error):

> Unsupported HTTP response status 415
>   Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
>   was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.

How do I change the content type? I can't find it in the NuSOAP forums/docs, or I might be overlooking something....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i know this is an old post, but i ran in to this page looking for an answer.

`application/soap+xml` is the content-type passed when using SOAP 1.2,
`text/xml` is used with SOAP 1.1,

something like this should do the trick,

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the encoding of NuSOAP streams with the webservices like that :

```
$client = new nusoap_client($params);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a slight omission in the NuSOAP library... it assumes that the content headers MUST be "text/xml", so if your client is attempting to connect to a service that outputs application/soap+xml headers, you'll end up with errors like:

> Response not of type text/xml: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

To test this, you may benefit from the following little function pattern, which I used to login to a SOAP service.  Remember, print out the client object!  You may not actually get a result to look at!

```
require_once('path/to/downloaded/libraries/nusoap.php');    
var $endpoint = 'https://somedomain.com/path/to/soap/server/Login';
var $client; // the soapclient object

function SOAP_Login()
{
    $this->client = new soapclient($this->endpoint);

    $err = $this->client->getError();
    if ($err) 
    {
        // Display the error
        echo '<p><b>SOAP Constructor error: ' . $err . '</b></p>';
        exit;
        // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
    }

    $params = array( 
        'some' => 'thing.. depends on what the WSDL expects'
    );

    $result = $this->client->call('someFunction', $params);     

    print_r($result);  // Without the fix, this prints nothing (i.e. false) !!!

    print_r($this->client); // Instead, look at the state of the client object, specifically error_str and debug_str
}
```

When I printed my $result, I got nothing, but when I printed out the $client object, I could see that there were errors.

The little hack I implemented was in the nusoap.php file, around line 7500.  Look for this if-statement:

```
if (!strstr($headers['content-type'], 'text/xml')) {
    $this->setError('Response not of type text/xml: ' . $headers['content-type']);
    return false;
}
```

And change it to this:

```
if (!strstr($headers['content-type'], 'text/xml') && !strstr($headers['content-type'], 'application/soap+xml') ) {
    $this->setError('Response not of type text/xml: ' . $headers['content-type']);
    return false;
}
```

All this does is it lets NuSOAP handle responses that issue an "application/soap+xml" header (which is a valid xml header).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this as well.

The secret is in the web.config
Change wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding

Like so:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="YourProject.View.Whatever.IYourService">
```

Hope that helps!
/Erik

Comment: I can't change it to basicHttpBinding, as we need wsHttpBinding for our certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

$client = new nusoap_client($params);

$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

The answer that is ticked as correct is not for NUSOAP therefore not the appropriate answer.